# Using .apply() on dataframe re-orders my columns into alphabetical order? Strange behavior

Tags: python, pandas

I am seeing some strange behaviour with an `.apply()` function.

I am calling an API, and editing the row with the response.

I can't upload the dataset for privacy reasons, but this is basically the function and simple example DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_customers':['John','Foo'],'email':['email@gmail.com','othermail@yahoo.com']})

print(df)

  my_customers                email
0         John      email@gmail.com
1          Foo  othermail@yahoo.com
```

And the api call:

```
def api_func(row):

    name=row['my_customers']
    email=row['email']

    # send api request 
    response = api(name, email)        

    # if there is data in the response
    if 'data' in response.keys():

        # append our data to row 
        row['api_status'] = 'Data Found'

        row['api_response']= response

        return row

    # otherwise flag no data found   
    else:

        row['api_status'] = 'No Data Found'

        return row
```

And the DataFrame after this apply() function. The columns have been re-ordered into alphabetical order:

```
df = df.apply(api_func,axis=1)


   api_status api_response                email my_customers
0  data found          xyz      email@gmail.com         John
1  data found          abc  othermail@yahoo.com          Foo
```

I have read the documentation and can't find any clues as to why this is happening. And i have never seen this happen before.

Any idea?

edit: full code:

```
def api_append(row):


    # set up variables
    api=get_api()
    firstname=row['firstname']
    lastname=row['lastname']
    email=row['email']
    phone=row['phone_only']
    countrycode=row['country_code']


#   send request

    request = SearchAPIRequest(email=email,minimum_match=0.8,first_name=firstname,
                           last_name=lastname,phone=phone,country_code=countrycode,api_key=api)


# if there is an error, record it to the dataframe

    try:
        response = request.send()
        response = response.to_dict()

    except (ValueError, AttributeError) as e:

        # append our error data to the row 
        row['Pipl_Api_Status'] = 'check error code'

        row['Pipl_Api_response']= str(e)

        return row


    # if there is data in the response
    if 'data' in response.keys():

        # append our data to row 
        row['Api_Status'] = 'Data Found'

        row['Api_response'] = response['data']

        return row

    # otherwise flag no data found   
    else:

        row['Api_Status'] = 'No Data Found'

        return row

df_sample = df_sample.apply(api_append,axis=1)
```

Comment: `df = df.apply(api_func,axis=1)` Also edited original question. If you need any more info let me know

Comment: Are you sure if it does something like that? I cannot replicate the issue.

Comment: It is very puzzling... the code in my question is basically the same. I left nothing out. i have been trying to debug it for an hour. It re-arranges the order of the columns in alphabetical order! However, I think I found a solution, even though I can't explain it. Before applying the function,  I create the new columns: `row['api_status'] = np.nan` and `row['api_response']= np.nan` first, rather than creating them inside the `apply()` function. The order of the columns are no longer changed.

Comment: I am curious.  Could you try this code: `import random
def api_func(row):
    name=row['my_customers']
    email=row['email']

    response = random.randint(0,9)
    # if there is data in the response
    if response % 2 == 0:
        row['api_status'] = 'Data Found'
        row['api_response']= 'response'
        return row
    
    else:
        row['api_status'] = 'No Data Found'
        row['api_response'] = 'No response'
        return row
df = df.apply(api_func, axis = 1)`

Comment: @GokulKrishnanR your example works fine. I have edited my original question to include basically the full api call. It's a mystery.

Comment: @GokulKrishnanR, if you are still there. I kind of replicated it. Try this: remove `row['api_status'] = 'No Data Found' row['api_response'] = 'No response'` from your `else` statment.